# Use Mouse without Borders between two PCs in different networks

Tags: windows

I'm trying to find a solution similar to Mouse without Borders that works no matter what network the computers are connected to.

I need this because my Wi-Fi network is separate than my wired network.

For example, say Computer A is connected to Network A. Computer B is connected to Network B. Now connect the two computers. Is it possible?

Comment: How would you expect anything to communicate with anything on separate networks?

Comment: you could set up a VPN between them, or if they're routable between each other, simply set up the IP address manually.

Comment: @AthomSfere Assuming Network A and Network B were connected to a third network (say, the Internet) Journeyman's comment should work.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Yes, but then they are essentially the same network... which was really part of the point I was trying to make.

Comment: On Linux, there is `x2x` which routes keyboard and mouse input over `ssh`. Maybe you can use it with `Cygwin` on Windows.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that the wirless network is based within the wired network, you actually can use MWB version 2.1.2.1212 ([available here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460)!) to do this. You probably could with an earlier version as well, but this is the first one I'm sure that it works properly on.

The "secret sauce" is as follows...

1. Of course make sure that you are using the same exact Security Key on each machine. Don't forget that this is case sensitive.
2. Make sure the TCP box on the "Machine Setup" tab of the dialog is checked.
3. Take note of the adapter that you want to use (it's in the drop down list next to the TCP box) because you'll need to know the IP address of each machine to control/be controlled.
4. On the "controlling machine" (which is a misnomer because they're all really controlling machines) go to the "IP Mappings" tab and enter both the following (without the braces):

   **{computer name}{space}{IP Address}**

   So for a machine to be controlled named "SCAR" with an IP of 192.168.4.444 it would be:

   **SCAR 192.168.4.444**
5. Now go back to the "Machine Setup" tab on the controlling machine and click "Apply".
6. On the machine "to be controlled" (and assuming the controlling machine is "MUSTAFA 192.168.3.333") it would be:

   **MUSTAFA 192.168.3.333**
7. Now go back to the "Machine Setup" tab on the machine to be controlled and click "Apply".

When you see...

**Connected -->**

**<-- Connected**

... on the dialog of for each entry on both machines you're good to go.

What's described above works our internal networks which are on 10.www.xxx.yyy and 10.aaa.bbb.ccc, respectively. And yes, those octets use different letters because they represent completely different octects.

The only thing that I haven't gotten to work yet (and won't spend too much time to figure out right now) is how to get a machine connected to a router with one of those 10.www.xxx.yyy IPs but has its own DHCP server to be controlled by a machine on the 10.aaa.bbb.ccc side. With my limited networking knowledge I don't think this is going to be possible.

IHTH!

Comment: For those who aren't sure what their IP address is, you can run `ipconfig` in the command prompt. Copy your IPV4 address.

Comment: I was getting many IPv4 addresses from `ipconfig`, found the correct one to use in MWB IP mappings by running `for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %a in ('ping -n 1 -4 "%computername%"') do @echo %a` in the command line (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26074153/863923)

Answer (score 0):

> On the "controlling machine" (which is a misnomer because they're all really controlling machines) go to the "IP Mappings" tab and enter both the following (without the braces):
>
> {computer name}{space}{IP Address}

this worked for me, for some reason i had to use a DNS name rather than an IP address.

Comment: But he says in his post "{computer name}{space}{IP Address}". Computer name is the DNS name.